# How can I set WebView content scale (qml QT 5.2)

Tags: qt, webview, qml, qt5

I use qml WebView QT 5.2.

```
WebView {    
    anchors.fill: parent
    url: "http://google.com"   
}
```

Loaded page content is scaled depending on WebView width. How can I get default scale like in browser?

left picture my WebView, right - Google Chrome
[image]

Comment: Hi there, try to play with **QtWebKit.experimental** by `import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0 ` look at [QtWebKit.experimental](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html)

Comment: @Redanium thanks for the tip. Not really what I'm looking for. But interesting information anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the same scaling as in **Picture 2** from you question , you have to set the **user-agent property** of **WebView** to the *chrome one* as follow :

```
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0
...
WebView {    
anchors.fill: parent
url: "http://google.com"   
experimental.userAgent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36"
}
...
```

**[Update]**
notice the difference between the 3 images from 3 different user-agent strings

------------------------------------------***User-agent Android Browser***------------------------------------------------

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30    (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
```

[image: user-agent Android Browser]

------------------------------------------***user-agent Chrome Browser***------------------------------------------------

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"
```

[image: user-agent Chrome Browser]

------------------------------------------***user-agent  Ipad-Macosx/Safari***------------------------------------------------

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25"
```

[image: user-agent Ipad-Macosx/Safari]

Comment: Did you try this code? Doesn't make any effect for me. I'm using OS X 10.9.2 and QT 5.2.

Comment: yep, it worked on windows 7 64, Qt 5.2.1 and I even played with different user-agent strings .e.g Android Webkit user-agent, you got the same content as in android mobile browser...etc check this [User Agent String](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) and play with it.

Comment: I've read more about User Agent. I've just need find right combination of user agent string and website I want to display.

Answer (score 1):

Although this topic is pretty old, I had just encountered the same issue with QT 5.11 in a Ubuntu Touch app. Turned out that I just had to set the following:

```
    QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

(or `QApplication`, respectively)

Note that this must be set before the application instance is created:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication *app = new QGuiApplication(argc, (char**)argv);
```

This lead to the webview scaling the same way the native browser on ubuntu touch does (Morph browser). I did not need to set any user agent information.

For those also working with Ubuntu Touch, the `MainView` size does have a direct impact on content scaling in the webview. I left the defaults set by the creation process (`clickable create`), which is:

```
   width: units.gu(45)
   height: units.gu(75)
```

This leads to correct scalingon the device (in this case, a Volla Phone).