# Qt Quick WebKit 3.0 settings

Tags: qml, qt5, qtwebkit, qt-quick

I'm coding a **Qt Quick** app that contains a small web-page view and I can't find any settings for **WebKit 3.0** in the [QtWebKit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwebkit-index.html) or [QML QtWebView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtwebkit-webview.html) documentation.

- Q1 - How do I enable flash plugin?
- Q2 - How do I set a different [User Agent string](http://useragentstring.com/)?
- Q3 - How do configure disk cache and cookie cache?

Comment: Hey Yukarin, have you found out how to resolve any of these? See my answer regarding changing User Agent. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

### Changing the User Agent string

For changing the user agent string you could use this [QtWebKit.experimental extension](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html)

```
 import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0

 ...

 // and add this line in your WebView
 experimental.userAgent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356243/how-can-i-set-webview-content-scale-qml-qt-5-2)

But like you, I haven't found out yet about:

- How to enable flash plugins?
- How to configure disk cache? ...