# How to manage cookies and change user agent in WebView (QtQuick 2)?

Tags: qt, cookies, webview, qml, user-agent

I am working with Qt 5.7. In my project, I am using Qml WebView (import QtWebView 5.7). I would like to know how to manage (add, delete and modify) cookies and how to change the user agent of the WebView component. I have looked at the official documentation but couldn't find a way.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is not possible using plain QML, you have to stick to some low level C++ function which use `QNetworkCookieJar`. For details see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkcookiejar.html.

Comment: For userAgent refer to [how-can-i-set-webview-content-scale-qml-qt-5-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356243/how-can-i-set-webview-content-scale-qml-qt-5-2/22390754#22390754) but it's for Qt 5.2 , I don't know if it still valid for higher version of Qt